# How to add videos on my home page slider?

Tags: php, slideshow

How would you recommend adding videos to my [website](http://mamou-mani.com)'s home page slideshow, here is the php code that creates the slideshow:

```
<?php global $gpp; ?> 
<div class="app">
<div id="slideshow">
<?php
 $slides = array('gpp_slideshow_image_1','gpp_slideshow_image_2','gpp_slideshow_image_3');
 $i=0;
    foreach ($slides as $slide) {
        if($gpp[$slide]<>"") {
            echo '<div class="slide"><img alt="'.get_bloginfo('name').'" src="'.$gpp[$slide].'" /></div>',"\n";
        }
    }
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `gpp_slideshow...` ? It's not something from WordPress core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [GPP Slideshow](http://wordpress.org/plugins/gpp-slideshow/) description:

> The GPP Slideshow plugin for WordPress allows you to create **minimalist *image* slideshows**...

This plugin is built to only handle image slideshows, so I seriously doubt it could easily handle non-image content such as videos. You're much better off moving on to a slideshow that is built to handle multiple types of media. (Sidenote: And if that's the slideshow code then it's rather inaccessible anyway and you're better off moving on for that reason alone.)

As a rule I don't like slideshows so I don't use them much, but some plugins that might be better-suited to your task are [AnythingSlider](http://wordpress.org/plugins/anythingslider-for-wordpress/) (might be abandoned, though, so proceed at your own risk) or [one that uses FlexSlider 2](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/flexslider).